# How to handle comments in a web application database

Tags: php, mysql

What is the fastest method to do this? Should it be one giant table with indexing for each 'topic' or is it better to create a table for each topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't create a table per topic. Just create a comment table:

```
topic_comments
--------------
id
topic_id
comment_text
comment_author_id, etc
```